# Replace values in a file conditional on their value

Tags: awk, sed

I have a file full of numbers that range `10.00-10.66`, `20.67-21.33`, `30.67-31.33` and `40.34-42.00`.

Example input:

```
10.21  21.12  10.50  30.80
30.91  31.12  31.00  10.30
21.21  20.99  20.90  31.20
41.71  41.72  10.10  41.80
```

I want to convert the file such that:

```
10.00-10.20 = 0|0:[DOSE]
10.21-10.66 = .|.:[DOSE]
20.90-21.10 = 1|0:[DOSE]
20.67-20.89 = .|.:[DOSE]
21.11-21.33 = .|.:[DOSE]
30.90-31.10 = 0|1:[DOSE]
30.67-30.89 = .|.:[DOSE]
31.11-31.33 = .|.:[DOSE]
41.80-42.00 = 1|1:[DOSE]
41.34-41.79 = .|.:[DOSE]
```

Example output:

```
.|.:10.21  .|.:21.12  .|.:10.50  .|.:30.80
0|1:30.91  .|.:31.12  0|1:31.00  .|.:10.30
.|.:21.21  1|0:20.99  1|0:20.90  .|.:31.20
.|.:41.71  .|.:41.72  0|0:10.10  1|1:41.80
```

I can think of a way to do this in R, but the actual file is roughly 1000*5000000 elements in size, and I don't think R can cope!

Is there a way to conditionally replace all elements in a file dependant on their value with an in-line text editor like sed or awk? Alternative programs are welcome!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Search replace string in a file based on column in other file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20327179/search-replace-string-in-a-file-based-on-column-in-other-file)

Comment: Probably not the best person to comment, but I don't think its a full duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple way to do this in awk would be like this:

```
{
    for (i=1;i<=NF;++i) {
        if ($i>=10&&$i<=10.2) $i="0|0:"$i
        else if ($i>=10.21&&$i<=10.66) $i=".|.:"$i
        # etc.
    }
    print
}
```

That is, loop through each field of each record and add the strings you want depending on the value of the field. You can put the script in a file and run it like `awk -f script.awk input_file`

Comment: Big +1 for understanding the logic of the question!

Comment: Yeah, sorry, not well worded question - this works perfectly.